# How does the Fourier transform map a function into a distribution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

So far I understand how the Fourier transform maps Schwartz space into Schwartz space, $L^2$ to $L^2$, and how it can be extended to map tempered distributions to tempered distributions. However one point I do not understand yet is how the Fourier transform maps a function (I am not sure which function space is appropriate in this case) into a distribution. This is a claim made in a few textbooks, but I don't see how this can be seen from the definition of the Fourier transform.

How does the Fourier transform create a distribution from a function?

Comment: Any locally integrable function is a distribution. It is a tempered distibution with some additional conditions. For examle, $\int (1+|x|)^{-k}f(x)dx<\infty$ for some positive integer $k$ will do. Every tempered distribtion has a  FT (which is also a tempered distribution).

Comment: @geetha290krm We can create a distribution from any locally integrable function but where does the Fourier transform play a role here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t do it for every function. For example $e^x$ grows too fast at infinity to have a Fourier transform (even in the very general distributional sense).

Consider the mapping $\iota:L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^n)\to\mathcal{D}’(\Bbb{R}^n)$ mapping each locally-integrable function $f$ into its associated distribution ($\phi\mapsto \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f\phi$). Now, you know that the $\mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R}^n)\subset \mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ so taking duals reverses the inclusions, $\mathcal{S}’(\Bbb{R}^n)\subset \mathcal{D}’(\Bbb{R}^n)$, i.e every tempered distribution can naturally be thought of as a distribution. So, you can now consider the preimage $\mathcal{T}(\Bbb{R}^n):=\iota^{-1}[\mathcal{S}’(\Bbb{R}^n)]$ which is a subspace of $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, and is called the space of *tempered functions*. In words it just means those $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ functions whose induced distributions actually lie in the subspace of tempered distributions. This space consists of very many functions, including those that have polynomial growth in an integrated sense (as mentioned in the comments).

So, now you can certainly apply the Fourier transform. More precisely, consider the composition

\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}(\Bbb{R}^n)\xrightarrow{\iota} \mathcal{S}’(\Bbb{R}^n)\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}\mathcal{S}’(\Bbb{R}^n),
\end{align}
taking a tempered function to its naturally induced tempered distribution, and then taking its Fourier transform, which thus lands you in the space of tempered distributions.

Comment: Thank you! The key step I was missing was the implicit use of the map $i$ you defined.

Comment: @CBBAM yeaa but you should note that these things are often only said in words (the notations $\iota$ and $\mathcal{T}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ are not standard)